# D3 bar chart using time scale rectangles not aligning to x axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

hello world> I have been battling this problem for a while now. Im trying to create a bar graph that will take an array of objects as data with time being a date object and value being a number.

My Scale looks like this

```
d3.time.scale.utc()
           .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.time; }))
           .rangeRound([20, this.state.width - 60]).nice(data.length);
```

My rectangles are being drawn like this, using the same scale

```
      const self = this,
      xScale = this.state.xScale,
      yScale = this.state.yScale,
      barWidth = this.getBarWidth(data.length),
      bars = chart.selectAll('rect')
                   .data(data);
  // UPDATE
  bars
    .transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style('fill', color)
      .attr('x', function(d) { 
          console.log(xScale(d.time)- (barWidth / 2));
          return xScale(d.time) - (barWidth / 2); 
       })
      .attr('width', barWidth)
      .attr('y', function(d) { return yScale(d.value); })
      .attr('height', function(d) { return self.state.height - yScale(d.value); });
  // ENTER
  bars
    .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .style('fill', color)
      .attr('class', 'bar')
      .attr('x', function(d) { 
          console.log(xScale(d.time) - barWidth);

          return xScale(d.time) - barWidth; 
       })
      .attr('width', barWidth + (barWidth / data.length))
      .attr('y', function(d) { return yScale(d.value); })
      .attr('height', function(d) { return self.state.height - yScale(d.value); });
  // EXIT
  bars
    .exit()
    .transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style('fill', 'red')
      .style('opacity', 0)
      .remove();
```

I get the problem below where the ticks have some length and the axis another and the tick marks don't match the bars.

Please friends, help me find a solution to the below problem.

[My bar problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C3sm.png)

Comment: For what I see you translate your bars twice: once at the enter and once at the update. Maybe only one translation would suffice?

Comment: Are you saying there should be a bar on April 2?  Can you share your data, so we can reproduce the situation?  Or perhaps create an example jsFiddle or Plunker?

Comment: @Mark there are as many bars as there are rectangles. The labels are a little confusing, I have a task to have them be a lil more verbose in case multiple per day

Comment: @HuguesStefanski not sure where you are seeing multiple translations?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the x position. You set it during the update phase, then again during the enter phase, with a different result in each case.